# Как найти самый редкий элемент в массиве?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть большой массив

```
string[] = { "строка", "еще строка", "и еще одна строка", ... };
```

Очень многие строки совпадают. Как найти такую строку (необязательно все) в массиве, которая встречается реже всего?

Напрашивается решение: создать список структур

```
struct Stats
{
    string Element;
    int Count;
}

List<Stats> stats;
```

и, проходя по исходному массиву, заносить в список новую строку или наращивать счетчик, если строка уже есть в списке. А потом уже пройти по списку и выбрать тот, у которого счетчик наименьший.

Есть ощущение, что с linq можно сделать проще. Вопрос как?

Comment: А Вам какая характеристика алгоритма важна: время работы, используемая память или простота кода?

Comment: Главное - это простота кода.

Comment: Чёрт, я неправильно спросил :(. Я имел в виду не простоту кода, а его краткость. Поскольку через LINQ код, возможно, будет короче, но вряд ли проще…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не удержался и, всё же, написал на LINQ :).

```
string[] arr = { /* ... */ };
var query = (from str in arr
    group str by str into uStr
    orderby uStr.Count()
    select uStr.Key).Take(1);
res = query.First();
```

Answer (score 3):

Пока принимал душ придумал два решения (вернее, придумал-то много, выбрал два):

1. *Работает за линию (быстрее невозможно), памяти тратит много*.
   Заводим словарь (Map\HashMap\HashTable), ключ — строка, значение — число. Пробегаемся по списку, подсчитываем для каждой строки количество вхождений. Выбираем строку с наименьшим.
2. *Работает чуть дольше, дополнительной памяти требуется O(1)*.
   Сортируем массив. Теперь все одинаковые элементы будут идти подряд. Пробегаемся по массиву, подсчитывая для каждого элемента количество его вхождений и храним минимум. Бонусная оптимизация: как только нашли уникальный элемент, его и возвращаем.

LINQ, боюсь, тут не нужен…

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, если без каких-то новомодных наворотов, то надо сделать мапу string -> count и фигачаить её. Можно попытаться на ходу выстраивать уже отсортированный список.